# Dart tutorial on using Javascript libraries

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Is there a **new** tutorial on how to use a Javascript library in Dart? I'd like to use a color processing library (or better color-thief) in Dart, but I have not found a tutorial on how to use a complete library other than the generic example on dartlang.

Also people should start voting dart questions a bit more. [dart] homepage on stackoverflow still show old questions. It looks like no one is using dart here :(

(You can vote this question to the top if you want :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using JavaScript from Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/).

Comment: This is exactly what I've read before. Maybe I'm thick, but I wasn't able to use it for jquery or something "simpler" like the above mentioned color-thief.